# Can two proofs for exponents rely on each other?

Tags: solution-verification, proof-writing

The two proofs are negative exponents and zero exponents, shown respectively (ungeneralized).

*Proof*.

$$\begin{align}x^{-1}&=x^{-1}\\&=x^{-1}\cdot\frac{x^1}{x^1}\\&=\frac{x^{-1}\cdot x^1}{x^1}\\&=\frac{x^0}{x^1}\\&=\frac{1}{x^1}\end{align}$$

Thus $x^{-1}=\frac{1}{x^1}$. This proof depends on the fact that $x^0=1$, which follows.

*Proof*.

$$\begin{align}1&=1\\&=\frac{x^1}{x^1}\\&=x^1\cdot x^{-1}\\&=x^0\end{align}$$

Thus $x^0=1$. But, this proof depends on the fact that $x^{-1}=\frac{1}{x^1}$. Both these proofs depend on each other, which would suggest circular reasoning. Or, is this fine and I'm not crazy.

Comment: It is slightly circular. The issue is with definitions. Most commonly $x^{-1}$ is defined as the (unique) element for which $x^{-1}x=1$. So how do you define it? Generalising exponents is less about proof and more about definition

Comment: That said, you can ‘show’ $x^0=1$ differently. $$x^1=x^{1+0}\overset{!}{=}x^1\cdot x^0\therefore x^0=1$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You worries are justified, this is circular reasoning. You would have to prove one of the two without relying on the other, and then you can use it in the prove of the other.

In this specific case, I wonder what your definition of $x^k$ is or which properties you assume given. It seems to me that using $x^1 = x^1 \cdot x^0$ might be useful to establish that $x^0 = 1$, but again, I don't know your definitions.

Comment: Are you saying that the zero proof should not really be a proof at all, but a definition?

Comment: @Izzet808, I don't know what your definitions are, you would have to know :)

Comment: But that's the tricky thing with definitions, Definition: x^0 = 1. Can't we just say that? And x^k = x_1 * x_2 * ... * x_k.

Comment: You can define $x^0=1$, $x^k=x\cdot\cdots\cdot x$ ($k$ factors) for $k>0$ (people who are very strict will require a recursive definition for this) and $x^k = (1/x) ^ {-k}$ for $k<0$ (which of course means $-k>0$). We would then have to prove that $x^{k+l}=x^kx^l$ for all $k,l\in\mathbb Z$.

Comment: Ah, I see, thank you very much! I teach high school Algebra and wanted to show some bright students the logic behind negative exponents. But then another student asked about zero exponents. I had shown them this line of thinking and that satisfied them, but I then saw the reliance on each other (I didn't say anything to the students about this).

Comment: @Izzet808, in that case you do not prove, you motivate a definition. That is fine. You first show that if the $x^{k+l}=x^kx^l$ is supposed to hold for all integers, $x^1 = x^1 \cdot x^0$ forces you to have $x^0=1$ (for $x\ne 0$, but it always makes sense). And then $1=x^0=x^kx^{-k}$ forces $x^{-k}=1/x^k$. And I would indeed hope that that makes sense to all students, but I am an optimist and have never taught high school :)